# Multi selected Filter in Vue.js

Tags: vue.js

I have a selection of checkbox groups (hotel type and locations) and I want to filter the results based on what has been selected. How can I add my selectedLocations and types to the `filteredHotels()` method and get a filtered result. Sydney Hotels, Sydney Backpackers, Sydney or Melbourne hotels or all Hotels if only hotels is selected.

HTML

```
  <div>
    <div class="row pt-5">
        <div class="col">
            <h5>Locations</h5>
            <label v-for="(value, key) in locations">
                {{value}}
                <input type="checkbox" :value="value" v-model="selectedLocations">
            </label>
            {{selectedLocations}}
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row pt-5">
        <div class="col">
            <h5>Type</h5>
            <label v-for="(value, key) in types">
                {{value}}
                <input type="checkbox" :value="value" v-model="selectedTypes">
            </label>
            {{selectedTypes}}
        </div>
    </div>


    <transition-group class="row" style="margin-top:30px;" name="list" tag="div" mode="out-in">
        <div class="col-sm-4 pb-3 list-item" v-for="(hotel, index) in filteredHotels" :key="index">
            <div class="sau-card">
                <i class="fal fa-server fa-3x"></i>
                <h2>{{hotel.name}}</h2>
                <p>{{hotel.type}}</p>
                <p>{{hotel.location}}</p>

            </div>
        </div>
    </transition-group>
</div>
```

Data

```
data() {
        return {
            locations:['Sydney','Melbourne'],
            types:['backpackers','hotel','resort'],
            selectedLocations:[],
            selectedTypes:[],
            hotels:[
                {name:'a Hotel',location:'Sydney', type:'backpackers'},
                {name:'b Hotel',location:'Sydney', type:'hotel'},
                {name:'c Hotel',location:'Sydney', type:'resort'},
                {name:'d Hotel',location:'Melbourne',type:'hotel'},
                {name:'e Hotel',location:'Melbourne', type:'resort'},
                {name:'f Hotel',location:'Melbourne', type:'hotel'},

            ]
        }
    },
```

Computed

```
computed:{
    filteredHotels(){
        if(this.selectedLocations.length){
            return this.hotels.filter(j => this.selectedLocations.includes(j.location))
        }
        else if(this.selectedTypes.length){
            return this.hotels.filter(j => this.selectedTypes.includes(j.type))
        }
        else{
            return this.hotels;
        }
    }
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/stevenSAUaa/a8mq45op/2/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working example:

I've updated the condition under computed property as below: Include only location which is being selected. Instead of just returning the current selected location.

```
computed:{
        filteredHotels(){
        console.log(this.selectedLocations);
        if(!this.selectedLocations.length) {
            return this.hotels;
          } else {
          return this.hotels.filter(j => this.selectedLocations.includes(j.location))
          }
        }
    }
```

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    locations: ['Sydney', 'Melbourne'],
    types: ['backpackers', 'hotel', 'resort'],
    selectedLocations: [],
    selectedTypes: [],
    filtersAppied: [],
    hotels: [{
        name: 'a Hotel',
        location: 'Sydney',
        type: 'backpackers'
      },
      {
        name: 'b Hotel',
        location: 'Sydney',
        type: 'hotel'
      },
      {
        name: 'c Hotel',
        location: 'Sydney',
        type: 'resort'
      },
      {
        name: 'd Hotel',
        location: 'Melbourne',
        type: 'hotel'
      },
      {
        name: 'e Hotel',
        location: 'Melbourne',
        type: 'resort'
      },
      {
        name: 'f Hotel',
        location: 'Melbourne',
        type: 'hotel'
      },

    ]
  },
  methods: {
    setActive(element) {
      if (this.filtersAppied.indexOf(element) > -1) {
        this.filtersAppied.pop(element)
      } else {
        this.filtersAppied.push(element)
      }
    },
    isActive: function (menuItem) {
      return this.filtersAppied.indexOf(menuItem) > -1
    },
  },
  computed: {
    filterApplied: function() {
      if (this.filtersAppied.indexOf(element) > -1) {
        this.filtersAppied.pop(element)
      } else {
        this.filtersAppied.push(element)
      }
    },
    filteredHotels: function() {
      return this.hotels.filter(hotel => {
        return this.filtersAppied.every(applyFilter => {
          if (hotel.location.includes(applyFilter)) {
            return hotel.location.includes(applyFilter);
          }
          if (hotel.type.includes(applyFilter)) {
            return hotel.type.includes(applyFilter);
          }
        });
      });
    }
  }
})
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#app {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

li {
  margin: 8px 0;
}

h2 {
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

del {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div>
    <div class="row pt-5">
      <div class="col">
        {{filteredHotels}}
        <h5>Locations</h5>
        <label v-for="(value, key) in locations">
                {{value}}
                <input type="checkbox" :value="value" v-model="selectedLocations" :checked="isActive(value)" @click="setActive(value)">
            </label> {{selectedLocations}}
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row pt-5">
      <div class="col">
        <h5>Type</h5>
        <label v-for="(value, key) in types">
                {{value}}
                <input type="checkbox" :value="value" v-model="selectedTypes"
                :checked="isActive(value)"@click="setActive(value)">
            </label> {{selectedTypes}}
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-3 pb-4" v-for="hotel in filteredHotels">
        <div class="card text-center">
          <h1>{{hotel.name}}</h1>
          <p>{{hotel.location}}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Please check. I've updated the answer as per the question. Now it can be filtered with location + type both together.

Answer (score 1):

Pass your data via binding `this` or using `()=>`, e.g:

```
filteredHotels(){
   return this.hotels.filter(function (el) {
     return this.selectedLocations.includes(el.location) 
     || this.selectedTypes.includes(el.type)
   }.bind(this));
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gmxz3f1s/)